Please I, want to replace ckeditor content when selected option has change but dosent work
jquery part: le jquery que j'ai ajouter et le contenu ne change pas alors que le " alert(modele);" travaille bien
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("select.modele").change(function() {
            var modele = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
            $("#model-body").html("<span>Un élément span</span>");
            alert(modele);
        });
    });
</script>

text editor: le ckeditor dans lequel devrait s'opérer la modification mais cela ne marche pas
<textarea name="contenu" id="classic-editor" class="form-control" row="10" required>
     <div class="f-22" id="model-body">
                                                                  
     </div>
</textarea>

C'est ce que j'ai essayé mais ça ne marche pas

English language please.

Since the html inside textarea that means it's not rendered in the page and dom is not created, the easiest way to achieve that (not the only way) is to create a regular expression that finds the element you want to change and change it as a text like below:
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("select.modele").change(function() {
            var modele = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
            var textareaContent = $("#classic-editor").val();
            // Define a regular expression to match the content inside the model-body div
            var regex = /<div[^>]*?\bid\s*=\s*["']?model-body["']?[^>]*?>([\s\S]*?)<\/div>/;
            // Use replace method to replace the content inside the model-body div
            var modifiedContent = textareaContent.replace(regex, '<div class="f-22" id="model-body"><span>Un élément span</span></div>');
            // Update the content of the textarea with the modified content
            $("#classic-editor").val(modifiedContent);
            alert(modele);
        });
    });
</script>

